# Making card title an editable text field

Tags: html, css, bulma

So I am using a bulma card and instead of having just a fixed title I want to make the title an editable textfield. This is not difficult to achieve I just put the text field within

`<p class="card-header-title"> </p>`

What I get then is a text field that stretches over the whole width of the card. So how do make it smaller and left-aligned? So far i tried the size parameter of the text field and also using columns within the title with mixed results.

Comment: try this : <div class="card-header-title"><input type="text"> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. Using an `<input type="text" />`
2. Using `contenteditable` to make the `.card-header-title` editable

In the first option, we'll give the input a class so we can define a specific width.

The second option would require some JavaScript to update a `hidden` input field so you could access the updated title in a form, if needed.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-header-title-input {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.card-header-title--editable {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container is-fluid">
  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title">
        <input type="text" class="card-header-title-input" value="Component">
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec iaculis mauris.
        <a href="#">@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
        <br>
        <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title card-header-title--editable" contenteditable>
        Component
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
        <span class="icon">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec iaculis mauris.
        <a href="#">@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
        <br>
        <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="card-footer">
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Save</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Edit</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```